# Magento keeps changing an attribute's backend type from "int" to "varchar"

Tags: product, attributes

In Magento, you can't create a custom attribute of type "decimal" or "price".

But it's possible to create the attribute as text, and change the backend_type in it's database record from "varchar" to "decimal" or "int".  (table: eav_attribute)

But, Magento keeps changing it back to "varchar!!" Why?

Answer (score 8):

Magento will validate and change attribute `backend_type` when you save the attribute from admin panel (`Catalog > Attributes > Manage Attributes`).

I believe that the install script does not validate this so it's possible, for example, to create `select` attribute with `varchar` type. This does not mean it's OK to do it, in fact you should avoid it because you'll end up with a 'broken' attribute.

```
public function getBackendTypeByInput($type)
{
    $field = null;
    switch ($type) {
        case 'text':
        case 'gallery':
        case 'media_image':
        case 'multiselect':
            $field = 'varchar';
            break;

        case 'image':
        case 'textarea':
            $field = 'text';
            break;

        case 'date':
            $field = 'datetime';
            break;

        case 'select':
        case 'boolean':
            $field = 'int';
            break;

        case 'price':
            $field = 'decimal';
            break;
    }

    return $field;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

**Set `is_user_defined` to `0` in the `eav_attribute` entry.**

What Lord Skeletor is saying is right but you can easily stop Magento from resetting the `backend_type`.

See the `saveAction()` in `Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_AttributeController`:

```
if (is_null($model->getIsUserDefined()) || $model->getIsUserDefined() != 0) {
  $data['backend_type'] = $model->getBackendTypeByInput($data['frontend_input']);
}
```

So, if the `is_user_defined` value of the `eav_attribute` is set to `0`, the `backend_type` will not be overridden!

Comment: Hey @Tom, I have issue with multi-select attribute when i set is_user_define 0 attribute save time to give me js error..like as /magento216/pub/static/version1496830481/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/mage/backend/validation.js:205 Uncaught TypeError: this.trigger is not a function

Comment: Also FIY magneto defult attribute in multiselect type text and is_user_define is 0 give same error.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if I change set the "frontend_input" value to "", it won't overwrite the backend_type anymore, but then the product value won't be shown in the backend product view anymore.

The only way to add integer/decimal type and input seems to be, to write an extension for it.

I'm working on a shop which requires both types, I wonder why Magento does not support them by default.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using a MYSQL trigger as a workaround:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER topseller_int BEFORE UPDATE ON eav_attribute
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
  IF NEW.attribute_code = 'topseller' THEN
    SET NEW.backend_type = 'int';
  END IF;
END;$$

DELIMITER ;
```

So the backend_type of the attribute will always be int.